# PHP file_get_contents now gets forbidden error

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP application that will cycle through a list of URLs checking to see if the link is valid or not. The way I accomplish this is by opening the URL using the php function file_get_contents. I then search for a certain string value within the page source in order to determine if the link is good or bad. So in testing the application, towards the end of the day, whenever I would try to check a URL on this website I would get this message:

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in...

The message is a bit longer containing information about the location of my code but this part is the part that stood out to me. I'm thinking that maybe the companies router/firewall thinks I'm trying to spam/attack them based off what I have been Googling. I'm wondering if I might be on some permanent "blacklist" or something like that and how would I find out? I wasn't trying to do anything bad. Actually, what I'm doing will help out this company as I'm doing something that will help to generate sales. Total accident :-) I'm going to call the company later and ask them about it.

Comment: You should always gain permission before using a site's content.

Comment: Ask them. That's the best way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Many sites block access from user agents that fail to identify themselves. Introduce yourself properly and you're likely to get better service.

```
ini_set('user_agent', "CharlesUserAgent1.0"); // Anything usually should do as long as it's not blank
```

**EDIT:** You may also want to check out [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), it does a much better job at making HTTP requests than PHP's builtin URL fopen wrappers.

Comment: As an alternative to cURL, you could use any one of the fine PHP HTTP client libraries that aren't coded by demons.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering how I would use cURL to read in the html source of a web page? I'm able to do this with file_get_contents. Then from there I can use the strpos function to search for the html I'm looking for.

Comment: @Charles: There are lots of good examples in the PHP manual for cURL. This page has a demonstration how to load a web page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

1. it could be the websites check the user_agent header and then blocks your request.
2. Some URLs could be having a query string and the file_get_contents might not be able to perform your request as a normal browser would, thus the page you will be requesting could be something which is actually forbidden :/

Browse the URLs manually and see if you get the same error

Comment: They also may have gotten sick of the repeated requests and banned his IP using the Apache `Deny` directive (returns a 403)

Comment: Yeap totally forgot about that nice addition